# Proper loss function

Tags: neural-networks, categorical-data, binary-data, loss-functions, autoencoders

I'm working with a dataset dealing with product sales in a supermarket. I'm using a large neural network (with large I mean I have many inputs compared to the number of training instances) to forecast the sales, but **I would like to reduce the input dimension, using an autoencoder**.

Let me describe the input data for one product (in my network I forecast $m$ products alltogether and I have input data associated to each one of them):

- $0/1$ flag, but $0$ for most training istances, indicating stockout, basically if $1$ the product is not available and the number of sales for that product on that day will be $0$.
- count data $X \in \big\{0,1,\dots,m\big\}$, but 0 for most training istances, representing the number of promotions active on that product that day.
- Real number representing the product price, but $X_i \in {x_1,x_2,..,x_k}$ i.e. it assumes at most k different values over the training period for almost all products.

As I said before, I have these 3 inputs multiplied by $m$ number of products, so $3m$ inputs. I want to reduce the size of the input, by using an autoencoder. This means that my inputs are also my outputs and I would like to encode my input in a lower dimensional space and then decode it and reconstruct it. If I accomplish that I would be able to reduce the size of my *forecasting network*.

**Now, I don't have a clue about which loss measure I should use for such data and I kindly ask for your help**.

One idea I had was to transform the 2 categorical(ordinal) inputs into $k$ dummy variables (where $k$  is the number of levels), in that case it's like a multilabel classification problem, so that I would use a binary crossentropy loss function and sigmoids on the output layer.

Comment: What are you predicting? What are your features?

Comment: Autoencoder, I'm reconstructing the input after compressing it to achieve dimensional reduction. 

Those listed are my features

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It wasn't clear to me how the auto-encoder entered into your analysis.